# Asp.net MVC retrieving a model object from a ViewModel

Tags: design-patterns, data-binding, asp.net-mvc-2

So I am using ViewModels to pass data from/to the web forms in my MVC application, as seems to be recommended practice from what I have read.

My question is what is the normal approach to then map the ViewModel into an actual domain entity?

I'm guessing I should probably add a 'GetObject' method to my ViewModels so I have something like:

```
[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
public void CreatePerson(PersonViewModel model)
{
    Person p = model.GetPerson();
    _repository.Save(p);
}
```

Is this the right approach? It seems like I'm creating a lot of unecessary work for myself by using ViewModels in this way.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you're binding your controls to properties of the Person object in the View like so

```
<% Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Person.Name) %>
```

You can have the following method to accept only the person model

```
[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)] 
public void CreatePerson([Bind(Prefix="Person")]Person person) 
{ 
    _repository.Save(person); 
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand, or I think you might be missing the point. I don't expose the underlying Person object in anyway to the front end. All data is passed to/from front end as formatted string data in a ViewModel (which is created from the Person entity).

Comment: Ahh yea, you're might be taking the abstraction between View and Model a little too far.  i prefer the approach of wrapping Models in ViewModels and binding them to the View.  It also allows me to have DataAnnotations applied on the Model validated in the View.